# Stripe payment page Connection is not secure problem

Tags: reactjs, npm, stripe-payments

I used **react-stripe-checkout** npm for making a donation payment page. Everything working fine. But in some browsers, it says  [**Connection is not secure**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAxH1.jpg) and some browsers don't show any problem on connection.

2nd Problem. In the console, there's showing an error multiple times -

> [Report Only] Refused to apply inline style because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'.
> Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-vm6IzvFZd99ObdwJODb8jyYg2jyzf6SewoA692PD8/A='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this `Connection is not secure` warning showing in the Stripe Checkout page or the website that host your web application? If it's on your website then you might want to check your SSL certification configuration.

The 2nd error is related to the Content Security Policy, you can find the Stripe CSP directives here https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#content-security-policy